# Table of content header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, koma-script

I need a header on ALL the TOC-pages, like the headers of `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` and on the second page of the Table of Contents (Inhaltsverzeichnis). Right now there is no header on the first TOC-page. Please tell me what to do.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}       
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\KOMAoptions{parskip=true,fontsize=12,toc=flat,twoside=false,numbers=nodotatend,toc=listof,toc=index,}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{babib.bib} 
\usepackage{geometry}       
\geometry{a4paper, top=20mm, left=30mm, right=20mm, bottom=25mm} 
\linespread{1.25} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\hspace{1cm}#1}{}}   
\chead{}       
\ihead{\leftmark}   
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\bfseries}   
\setheadsepline{0.5pt} 

\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}\chapter{test}

\listoffigures
\ihead{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings} 
\listoftables
\ihead{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings} 
\appendix
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean the page that has the "Inhaltsverzeichnis" chapter on it? You'd need to change the chapter page style for that.

Comment: Yes, page nb. 1 needs the same header as page nb. 2. How do you change the pagestyle of \tableofcontents?

Comment: If you have a LOF or LOT with more than one page its first page will not have a header. `\listoffigures\thispagestyle{scrheadings}` results in pagestyle `scrheadings` on the *last* page of LOF.

Comment: Note, if you put commands after `\listoffigure` the will be executed after printing the list of figures. So `\ihead{…}` and `\thispagestyle{…}` in your example can not change anything on the first page of the list of figures but only the last one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that package `scrpage2` is deprecated for a long time. Use its successor `scrlayer-scrpage` with similar syntax.

Do not set `\ihead` etc. manually inside the document. Do not redefine `\chaptermark` to change the format of the chapter number in header. Redefine `\chaptermarkformat` instead.

If you really want to use (I do not recommend this) pagestyle `scrheadings` on the first pages of TOC, LOF and LOT, use

```
\BeforeStartingTOC{\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}
```

in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[
  parskip=full,
  fontsize=12pt,
  toc=flat,
  twoside=false,
  numbers=nodotatend,
  toc=listof,
  toc=index,
]
{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\addbibresource{babib.bib}% I do not have this bib file
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=20mm, left=30mm, right=20mm, bottom=25mm} 
\linespread{1.25}

\usepackage[
  automark,
  headsepline=.5pt
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter\hspace{1cm}}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\BeforeStartingTOC{\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}% pagestyle scrheadings on first page in TOC, LOF and LOT

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\appendix
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

---

Note that the other chapter pages still use pagestyle `plain`. If all chapter pages should get pagestyle `scrheadings` too, redefine `\chapterpagestyle` in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}
```

If all pages with pagestyle `plain` should get the header and the line below the header, use the starred version of `\ihead`: `\ihead*{\leftmark}` and add option `plainheadsepline` to the package options of `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess there is a problem when using \input before \tableofcontents regarding the header: Only the line is shown, but not the chaptername. But if I copy-paste the content of \input directly into the code the header is correctly shown.

Comment: @JoE1205 No. `\input` does not influence the mark mechanism of TeX and so does not change the running head. It only changes the input stream from one file to another.

Comment: Okay, the real problem is using \chapter* in the \input files. How to fix this?

Comment: Use `\addchap` instead `\chapter`. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402040/43317.